# List contents of zip file on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have (huge) zip files (not gzip) sitting on HDFS.  These files all contain multiple files.  Is there any way, other than pulling it to local, to list the files in the zip file?  Like zipinfo does on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

HDFS does not support processing zip files.

i understand that listing files in a zip file is too simple to code java for it but
you may want to try processing them with MapReduce

try [ZipFileInputFormat](https://github.com/cotdp/com-cotdp-hadoop/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cotdp/hadoop/ZipFileInputFormat.java)